# TypeORM - Column type is not defined and cannot be guessed

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

A co-worker was getting the error `Column type for AnnouncementWidget#workspace is not defined and cannot be guessed`.

Notice the Column and PrimaryColumn decorators being used.

```
@Entity()
export class AnnouncementWidget {
  @Column({
    type: "text",
    nullable: false,
    unique: true,
    comment: "Workspace (company/subdomain) that these settings belongs to",
  })
  @Index()
  @PrimaryColumn()
  workspace!: string;

  @Column({
    type: "text",
    nullable: false,
    comment: "The announcement's title",
  })
  title!: string;

  @Column({
    type: "jsonb",
    nullable: false,
    comment:
      "The announcement's message. Stored as JSON because it includes rich text content.",
  })
  message!: object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The @Column and @PrimaryColumn decorators are mutually exclusive. @PrimaryColumn inherently is a @Column, so you don't need both.